# iOS - no triangle next to Apple Development Push Certificate in keychain

Tags: ios, xcode, keychain

There is no triangle next to my certificate on Keychain. What does that imply? I am not being able to export it to create a p12 either. I am very new to iOS development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the certificate lacks a private key.